# How do I dynamically assign button listeners in JQuery/HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with and id of foo and I want to add rows dynamically that have a button that do something. How can I assign the listeners for the buttons dynamically using JQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method to assign event listeners if your buttons are already present or use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) methods if the buttons are generated dynamically.

### Update:

Try with `live()` method:

```
$('.edit').live('click', function(){
  // your code here...
});
```

Comment: I tried using bind. I gave my button a class of edit and I selected based on $('.edit'). Am I doing something wrong if it's in a table?

Comment: Ok it works but rather than run the function once it runs it more than once. Is that supposed to happen? Is there a way I can just make the function run once?

Answer (score 0):

you can assign class to dynamically added buttons and write something like if class is adder

```
$(function(){
   $(".adder").live("click",function(){
        //do something
});
});
```